# How to generate random string and use that same generated String in a whole code?

Tags: java

I need to generate a random string and I want to use that same random generated string more than one time. For example I generate string "test" and I want to use it in several methods. How it could be done?

Comment: 1. Generate the string at the beginning. 2.Use it anywhere you want.

Comment: Like [xkcd: Random Number](https://xkcd.com/221/) I assume you rolled a die (fair enough) `public static final String RNDSTRING = "test";`

Answer (score 2):

Generate a random `String` by `UUID.randomUUID().toString()` and save it into a `public static final` field

```
public class YourClass {
    public static final String RANDOM_STRING = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
}
```

so you can access it from anywhere by

```
YourClass.RANDOM_STRING
```